Firestore emulator issues in local
Unable to view the added/updated data in firestore emulator from web/console
I am trying to connect firestore database with local emulator from my mac (M2), i have initialized firestore instance from my nest js application using below code
admin.initializeApp ({
  projectId: 'emulator-test1-cf1',
  databaseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
});

this.db = admin.firestore();

if (this.config.firestore.useEmulator) { 
  this.db.settings({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080, 
    ssl: false,
  });
}

I am using below commands to connect to emulator:
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:8080
gcloud emulators firestore start --host-port=127.0.0.1:8080
I am able add/update/delete operation getting success from codebase.
But unable to view the added/updated data in web/console using below url
http://127.0.0.1:8080/emulator/v1/project/emulator-test1-cf1/databases/(default)/documents

The url i am referring is correct? or any other configuration mistakes happened?
